# Backwards Euler Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am asked to code Backwards Euler for the given differential:

`dy/dt = sin(3*t)-2*y , y0=1.2 ,x = [0 8]`

I know that Euler Forward is:

`y= y+h*(sin(3*t)-2*y)`

and the general formula for Backwards Euler is:

`y = y_i + h*y_i+1`

I saw that for Backwards Euler,

`y_i+1 = y_i / (1 + h)`

so should my function be:

`y_i+1 = sin(3*t)/(1+h)`

`y = y + h *sin(3*t)/(1+h)`

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BE has the following numerical scheme: $y_{n+1}=y_n+h\cdot f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})$.

Just consider $f(t,y)=\sin(3t)-2y$.

You'll get: $y_{n+1}(1+2h)=y_n+h\cdot \sin(3t_{n+1})$, and then

$y_{n+1}=\frac{y_n+h\cdot \sin(3t_{n+1})}{(1+2h)}$, where $y_0=1.2$.

$h$ is given by $h=\frac{N}{8}$, where $N$ is the number of discretization points

Note that this is a **linear** ODE, and then you can collect together the $y_{n+1}$-term. Otherwise, you should solve at each time-step a *non-linear* equation which defines implicitely $y_{n+1}$.

Anyway, your code will be just a for loop for $n$ which ranges from $1$ no $N$ and you can compute each $y_n$ with the expression above.

**EDIT**

As I wrote in the second(!) line, you have just to write the current expression for $f$ as a function of $t_{n+1},y_{n+1}$.

$y_{n+1}=y_n+h \cdot (\sin(3t_{n+1})-2y_{n+1})$

$y_{n+1}=y_n+h \cdot \sin(3t_{n+1})-2h \cdot y_{n+1})$

Now we need to write $y_{n+1}$ as a function of $y_n$, so we can compute *explicitely* at each time step $y_n$. So, we collect $y_{n+1}$.

$y_{n+1}+2 h \cdot y_{n+1}=y_n+h \cdot \sin(3t_{n+1})$

$y_{n+1}(1+2h)=y_n+h \cdot \sin(3t_{n+1})$

and hence, by dividing:

$y_{n+1}=\frac{y_n+h \cdot \sin(3t_{n+1})}{(1+2h)}$

Comment: How did you get $y_{n+1}(1+2h)=y_n + h*sin(3t_{n+1})$?

Comment: See my last edit

Comment: there's nothing to invent... I jus used the definition of the rhs given by the problem. Look at the edit

Comment: Oh I got it now. Thank you very much for your help!  :)